# gcm RegistrationIntentService no registration

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, message

so I am using gcm and when I try to register I successfully send the token to my back-end and it sends it to gcm with a 200 reply. The only problem is its a 200 reply but always says not registered and creates an on failure. I wanna find out if its front end or back end problem would help alot thanks. this is my RegistrationIntentService

```
package com.example.caesar.gcm;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    Context mContext = this;

    public String myData="";
    public String streamTitle = "",path="";

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("Server", ">>>onCreate()");
    }

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
        Log.i(TAG, "ygfuyvjunvvgu");
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {

            Log.d(TAG,"HERERERERERER");
            SharedPreferences appPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("com.example.gcmclient_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String token = appPrefs.getString("token", "");
            assert token != null;
            if (token.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    getGCMToken("10426431"); // Project ID: xxxx Project Number: 0123456789 at https://console.developers.google.com/project/...
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);
            subscribeTopics(token);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }


    private void getGCMToken(final String senderId) throws Exception {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String token = "";
                try {
                    InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(mContext);
                    token = instanceID.getToken(senderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                    if (token != null && !token.isEmpty()) {
                        SharedPreferences appPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("com.example.gcmclient_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = appPrefs.edit();
                        prefsEditor.putString("token", token);
                        prefsEditor.commit();
                    }
                    Log.i("GCM_Token", token);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("id", token);

        client.post("", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started
            }

            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, PreferenceActivity.Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            }

            public void onFailure(int statusCode, PreferenceActivity.Header[] headers, JSONObject errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                // called when request is retried
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     *
     * @param token GCM token
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
   }
```

}

//server side

```
var options = 
    { 
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization':'key=VALUE'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
        "to" : gcmId,
        "data" : {
            message: message
        },
        })
    }
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if(error) console.log(error);
        console.log("RESPONSE STATUS: " + response.statusCode)
        console.log("BODY: " + body);
        res.json({response: response.statusCode}); 
        });
```

Comment: You should post your server-side (back-end) app's code pls.

Comment: sure i kinda pasted it weird tho sry

Comment: You mean that gcmId is the token the server received from the client app? Have you tried clear data from installed client app, then re-run the app to get a new token, then send this new token to server?

Comment: yes that gcmId is the token i send to the server and yes i do that every time i wanna re test

Comment: Hi, I suggest that you put `sendRegistrationToServer(token); subscribeTopics(token);` into `doInBackground()` inside `getGCMToken`. I have not ever used the above code in service so I cannot make sure whether the token getting changed automatically and your client app not updating it on server app on the change.

Comment: Could you confirm that the gcmId on your server side is the same as the latest generated InstanceID token.

Comment: Ya I tried putting those functions inside and they don't even get the token correctly. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. And I'm going to check what the token is that my server gets kroikie

Comment: Did you find solution i faced this issue some time i dont know why but mostly it register but sometimes it failed